# Advice needed for Laravel 4 project structure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm quite new to Laravel 4 (Laravel is my first PHP MVC framework) and need a little help structuring my project.

1/ I need to include the the json-rpc classes found here jsonrpcphp.org in my project and am not quite sure the best place to put these.

2/ Where is the best place to do my initial setup/connection to my data source? Should this be inside of my controller or should this be placed elsewhere?

```
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
$connection = new jsonRPCClient('http://user:password@127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: May be this helps. http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11004.

Answer (score 1):

I think and pretty sure the best way to do it is [to create a Service](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers)

1. Put anywhere securely and can be easily accessed via `composer`. Look into how add autoloading to composer http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
2. as I said, create a service. look into Laravel IoC Container http://laravel.com/docs/ioc and [How to define Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers)

see example: [DatabaseServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseServiceProvider.php)

Related: optional for nice syntax [create a Facade](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) for it.